# DllImport in AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda

I'm pretty new in Lambda.

I created a new Lambda function and successfully could consume it via REST.

Now, I need to call a simple function that is in an external DLL. I included the DLL in the BIN and also in the root folders (checked that the DLL is copied to that directory) but when I call the Lambda function I get an error message that said the DLL was not found.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to call an external DLL on a Lambda Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, in some point.

I needed to build the project into a VM with Linux, and there I got the `.so` file which is the equivalent to the `.dll`. And I included that file in my project, and changed the `DLLImport` declaration to reflect the new extension.

Finally, I deployed to AWS Lambda and all works fine.